# IntegrityError at /signup-login/ duplicate key value violates unique constraint sts

Tags: python, django

i am getting this "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myblog_profile_email_3f46e9ef_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists." error every time when i submit my signup form even with new email address.values save inside User table but it not redirect it on home page.
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=120)
    bio=models.TextField(blank=True)
    gender_choices=(('M','Male'),('F','Female'),('S','Special'))
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=gender_choices,default='M')
    age=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=12)


    def __str__(self):
        msg = "Name : {0} {1}|| Email : {2} || gender : {3}".format(self.first_name,self.last_name,self.email,self.gender)
        return msg

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def ensure_profile_exists(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('created', False):
            Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    # first_name=forms.CharField(max_length=40,help_text="first Name")
    # last_name=forms.CharField(max_length=40,help_text="first Name")
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=120)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('username','email','password1','password2')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate
from .models import Profile
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'myblog/home.html')


def signUp(request):
    form=SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user=form.save()
        user.refresh_from_db()
        # user.profile.first_name=form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        # user.profile.lastname=form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        user.profile.email=form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        user.save()
        username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        login(request,user)
        return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
    else:
        print('form not submitted successfully \n')
        form=SignUpForm()
    return render(request,'myblog/signup.html',{'form':form})
```

[image: form entries are fresh]

[image: there is only 2 user]
[image: this error occur]

[image: but user successfully created]

i am new please also help me to explain why thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you have a unique constraint on the email column but not in your model. Have you run makemigrations/migrate?

Comment: thank you so much ,sorry i do this silly mistake i hope i will never do that again .thank you ,